# Delay in switching tabs android tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am having performance issue while switching between tabs in tablayout. In scenario one when i have less records i am able to switch between tabs easily and user doesn't fee any delay. Where as when i have more data user can feel lag like shown in below screenshot. Though screen loads after few seconds it is quite visible to user. Can someone suggest areas i can check to improve this further. Below is issue and current Fragment code...

UI -

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    dbConnection = new databaseHelper(getContext());
    dbConnection.getWritableDatabase();
    profileFragment = view.findViewById(R.id.profileFragment);
    downloadData = profileFragment.findViewById(R.id.dwnldData);
    refresh = profileFragment.findViewById(R.id.refreshdata);
    search = profileFragment.findViewById(R.id.search);
    removeFilter= profileFragment.findViewById(R.id.removeFilter);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    currmelas = dbConnection.findMelas("YES","YES","");

    downloadData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    });



    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1){
        candidateData = dbConnection.findHighCandData(mela_id,"1","");
    } else {
        candidateData = dbConnection.findHighCandData(mela_id,"","");
    }


    if (candidateData.size() <= 0) {
        if (currmelas.size() == 0 ){
            downloadData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(userSettings.size()==0){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    } else {            

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setScrollView(candidateData);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 100);

    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, i didn't find any post on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your data Loading to background worker and do not load information on the UI thread. This way you are not delayed while grabbing content between tab switching. I had the same problem, and had to move all my data loading to separate threads to enable clean smooth UI. After it is loaded, make sure you have set number of cached page off screen limit to keep what is important to avoid reloading on each swipe.

more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i tried option you suggested. I see slight improvement but its still visible to user.

Comment: After posting message i realize another workaround to improve it further and it did worked. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: No worries, @7toes.fablwesh mentioned using Loaders, this is a very optimized way to do it, but can be a bit much to learn your first time. I was assuming you are using background tasks to APIs to pull in your content and Recycler Views with onBindView to keep it clean it fast, but if you are using local data or up for the challenge of learning asyncTaskLoaders you can read more here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my solution so it will be helpful for others. In my code i was loading profiles in Loop, so whenever i have around 200 profile it use to take time to load and user can see lag. As @Sam mentioned i moved code in below handler and it resolved my issue. Now the system shows tab instantly and data gets loaded after few seconds which is better than earlier lag.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setScrollView(candidateData);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 100);
```